# Как сделать чтоб анимация иконки была и у текста

Tags: html, css, css-animation

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтоб анимация иконки была и у текста,т.е чтоб при наведении на иконку цвет менялся и у текста ( сердечко .heart )
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 200px;
}


.navlist  {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.navlist>img {
    width: 60px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.navlist a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 1.5em;
}

.gorod {
    padding: 1.5em;
}

.icons {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

.icons a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.heart {
    background-color: #8b8888;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    display: inline-block;
    width:35px;
    height:35px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:45px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.8s;
    margin-top: 17px;
    float: right;
}

.heart a {
}

#heart {
    font-size: 25px;
    transition: 0.8s;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

#heart:hover {
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.heart:hover {
    background-color: #f80909;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.theart {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 25px;
    justify-content: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: black;
}

.theart a {
    color: black;
}

.theart a:hover {
    color: red;
}

.bag {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 17px;
}

.bag a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tbag a {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 17px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
    margin-top: 25px;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flowers</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/style.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn-uicons.flaticon.com/uicons-regular-rounded/css/uicons-regular-rounded.css'>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3929e16ef5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'network/functions.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn-uicons.flaticon.com/uicons-regular-rounded/css/uicons-regular-rounded.css'>
  </head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
         <ul class="navlist" >
          <img src="static/images/logo.png" alt="">
            <li><a href="">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Условия возврата</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Отзывы</a></li>
            <li class="gorod">Уфа</li>
            <li class="nomer"><a href="">+7 (762) 283-93-88</a></li>
          </ul>


            <div class="icons">
              <div class="heart">
        <a href=""><i id="heart" class="far fa-heart"></i></a>
        
      </div>
      <div class="theart">
          <a href=""><p>Избранное</p></a>
        </div>
          <div class="bag">
              <a href=""><i class="fi fi-rr-shopping-bag"></i></a>
            </div>
       <div class="tbag">
                <a href=""><p>Корзина</p></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          
      </div>
    </div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: начните с того, что нужно засунуть в одну <a> картинку и текст. А потом даёте :hover не картинке или тексту, а ссылке, то есть их родителю, выглядеть будет так  - "a:hover .fi, a:hover span {}". Таким образом будут меняться иконка и текст одновременно.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно поместить текст и иконку в одного родителя. Тогда при наведении на этот блок можно будет  объектами, которые внутри него

```
<div class="wrap-block">
  <i id="heart" class="far fa-heart"></i>
  <span class="icon-text">Избранное</span>
</div>




.wrap-block:hover .icon-text{
  color: red;
}
```

Это сработает для тега с `.icon-text` в момент, когда наведут на `.wrap-block`.

При этом, данный CSS можно одновременно применить для нескольких блоков внутри `.wrap-block`

```
.wrap-block:hover .icon-text, .wrap-block:hover #heart{
      color: red;
 }
```

Для того чтобы текст был выровнен вертикально по центру, родительский класс можно сделать флексом и расположить все элементы на одной линии по вертикали

```
.wrap-block{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Чтобы сердце было белым по наведении на родителя, можно добавить слелующий код:

```
.wrap-block:hover #heart{ 
color: white; 
}
```

P.S. Тег p в таком случае лучше убрать, т.к. вкладывать блочные теги в строчные - это ошибка

Comment: Спасибо,помогло.Но я когда навожу на само сердечко,оно еще обводится белым,а если на текст ,то оно.И как еще поднять текст,чтоб он шел справа от сердца ? В сам вопрос прикрепил скрины

Comment: @Atu Нужно, чтобы по наведении на текст, он не менялся? Не совсем просто понял вас. Добавил ответ про выравнивание

Comment: Нужно чтоб при навидении на текст,в кружке так же появлялась белый обводка сердечка

Comment: Я в вопрос добавил скрины.На первом скрине это сердечко,когда я навожусь на текст,а на втором ,когда на сердечко

Comment: @Atu Я дополнил свой ответ